# Batch export and ungroup SVG to PNGs of each layer/group

Tags: matlab, svg, imagemagick, inkscape, batik

I have a folder of SVG images and I was looking at how I might be able to save each layer (group) of the SVG to a separate PNG file. I was working in Matlab, but I haven't seen any method that works for SVGs. I looked at a few external libraries, Batik being the main one, but I don't know enough XML to get this to work. I looked at Inkscape too, but its [export options](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine-Export.html) only seem to allow you to work with the entire rasterized image. I also looked at ImageMagick, but only found a layers method that seemed to make GIFs rather than the layers I want from the SVG.

Update: realized I can use ImageMagick to save layers this way `convert image.svg[1] output.png`, I still don't know 1) how to batch ungroup the layers in the SVG (they're ungroupable for sure--I checked in Illustrator) and 2) count how many layers I have in each SVG so I can go through all the layers to save them individually.

Comment: Does [this](http://superuser.com/questions/260047/batch-convert-svg-images-to-desired-size-png-or-ico) question help you?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Thanks, it does help the part of the problem where I'm trying to convert a single layer to the PNG. But I'm still stuck on the other parts of the problem (I've added some clarification in an update section).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of "scenes" (a.k.a. layers) in a multi-layer file with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
convert image.svg -ping -format '%n' info:
```

Alternatively, if you run the following command it will give the dimensions and colourspace, and type of each layer, one layer per line of output (so count the lines for the number of layers):

```
identify image.svg
```

I don't think you will have much success dealing with groups - though I have not tried myself as I don't have any multi-layer SVGs lying around - because **ImageMagick** is primarily a raster image editor and it *"outsources"* (or in **ImageMagick** parlance, it *"delegates"*) its vector handling to **librsvg**.

You may have some success with [this Github code](https://github.com/berteh/svg-objects-export).

```
https://github.com/berteh/svg-objects-export
```